# How can I unpack uint32_t byte streams in php?

Tags: php

As php is not supporting uint32_t data type, I have an issue when I communicate with a server over TCP_Socket. The server is sending byte streams as unint32_t (this is data type in c/c++). I tried to unpack these bytes by using unpack but it gives negative number or unexpected value. Here is my socket communication:

```
$host    = "127.0.0.1";
    $port    = 555;
    // create socket
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP) or die("Could not create socket\n");
    // connect to server
    socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not connect to server\n");  
    // read data from server
    $result = socket_read ( $socket , 1024 ) or die("Could not read server response\n");
    $tt= TcpSocket::_uint32be($result);
    sprintf('%u', $tt);
    echo " Test == ". $tt;
    echo "1-replay from server :";
    echo var_dump($tt);
```

Here is the function I use to convert the bytes to uint32_t to var.

```
public static function _uint32be($bin) 
{ 
    // $bin is the binary 32-bit BE string that represents   the integer 
    if (PHP_INT_SIZE <= 4){ 
        list(,$h,$l) = unpack('n*', $bin); 
        return ($l + ($h*0x010000)); 
    } 
    else{ 
        list(,$int) = unpack('N', $bin); 
        return $int; 
    } 
}
```

How can I unpack or retrieve uint32_t in php?

Comment: sure you got the right endianness? maybe it's `v` (big endian) instead of `n` (little endian)

Comment: The stream in little endian for sure but I have tried v as well but none of them result the expected output